# html css js button onclick removing and adding class

Tags: javascript, html, css, button

I know there are a lot of question similar but none have helped me so I'm here.
I have a 9 button grid, if i click one it change color (orange) but if i click another one they both stay orange. i don't want it. i want that if a button is already orange, the new one get colored but the first one return to normal color. I tried in a lot of ways but i'm not so good at js and HTML so i'm not understanding where the problem is

```js
function hide() {
  var x = document.getElementById("demo");
  var y = document.getElementById("demo2")
  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "inline-flex";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "inline-flex";
  }
  if (y.style.display === "inline-flex") {
    y.style.display = "none"
  }
}

function hide2() {
  var x = document.getElementById("demo2");
  var y = document.getElementById("demo");
  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "inline-flex";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "inline-flex";
  }
  if (y.style.display === "inline-flex") {
    y.style.display = "none"
  }
}

document.getElementById('sel').onclick = function() {

  var className = ' ' + sel.className + ' ';
  var a = document.getElementById('sel2');
  var b = document.getElementById('sel2');
  var c = document.getElementById('sel3');
  var d = document.getElementById('sel4');
  var e = document.getElementById('sel5');
  var f = document.getElementById('sel6');
  var g = document.getElementById('sel7');
  var h = document.getElementById('sel8');
  var i = document.getElementById('sel9');

  if (~className.indexOf(' btn ')) {
    this.className = className.replace(' btn ', 'btn2 ');
    this.a = a.replace(' btn2 ', 'btn ')
    this.b = b.replace(' btn2 ', 'btn ')
    this.c = c.replace(' btn2 ', 'btn ')
    this.d = d.replace(' btn2 ', 'btn ')
    this.e = e.replace(' btn2 ', 'btn ')
    this.f = f.replace(' btn2 ', 'btn ')
    this.g = g.replace(' btn2 ', 'btn ')
    this.h = h.replace(' btn2 ', 'btn ')
    this.i = i.replace(' btn2 ', 'btn ')

  } else {
    this.className = className.replace('btn2 ', 'btn ');
  }
}

document.getElementById('sel2').onclick = function() {

  var className = ' ' + sel2.className + ' ';

  if (~className.indexOf(' btn ')) {
    this.className = className.replace(' btn ', 'btn2 ');
  } else {
    this.className = className.replace('btn2 ', 'btn ');
  }
}
document.getElementById('sel3').onclick = function() {

  var className = ' ' + sel3.className + ' ';

  if (~className.indexOf(' btn ')) {
    this.className = className.replace(' btn ', 'btn2 ');
  } else {
    this.className = className.replace('btn2 ', 'btn ');
  }
}
document.getElementById('sel4').onclick = function() {

  var className = ' ' + sel4.className + ' ';

  if (~className.indexOf(' btn ')) {
    this.className = className.replace(' btn ', 'btn2 ');
  } else {
    this.className = className.replace('btn2 ', 'btn ');
  }
}
document.getElementById('sel5').onclick = function() {

  var className = ' ' + sel5.className + ' ';

  if (~className.indexOf(' btn ')) {
    this.className = className.replace(' btn ', 'btn2 ');
  } else {
    this.className = className.replace('btn2 ', 'btn ');
  }
}
document.getElementById('sel6').onclick = function() {

  var className = ' ' + sel6.className + ' ';

  if (~className.indexOf(' btn ')) {
    this.className = className.replace(' btn ', 'btn2 ');
  } else {
    this.className = className.replace('btn2 ', 'btn ');
  }
}
document.getElementById('sel7').onclick = function() {

  var className = ' ' + sel7.className + ' ';

  if (~className.indexOf(' btn ')) {
    this.className = className.replace(' btn ', 'btn2 ');
  } else {
    this.className = className.replace('btn2 ', 'btn ');
  }
}
document.getElementById('sel8').onclick = function() {

  var className = ' ' + sel8.className + ' ';

  if (~className.indexOf(' btn ')) {
    this.className = className.replace(' btn ', 'btn2 ');
  } else {
    this.className = className.replace('btn2 ', 'btn ');
  }
}
document.getElementById('sel9').onclick = function() {

  var className = ' ' + sel9.className + ' ';

  if (~className.indexOf(' btn ')) {
    this.className = className.replace(' btn ', 'btn2 ');
  } else {
    this.className = className.replace('btn2 ', 'btn ');
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
  background-color: white;
}

.flex-col {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.flex-row {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.justify {
  justify-content: center;
}

.align {
  align-items: center;
}

.evenly {
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}

.between {
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.border {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.m-0 {
  margin: 0;
}

.spacer {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.grow {
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.orange {
  color: orange;
}

.bold {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.bg {
  background-color: whitesmoke;
}

.tabtitle {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.tariffe {
  font-size: small;
}

.intro {
  text-align: center;
}

.tartitle {
  font-size: medium;
}

div h2 {
  font-size: xx-large;
}

.cont {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 35px;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
  margin-top: 12px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.m-7 {
  margin-top: 7px;
}

.m-14 {
  margin: 14px;
  padding: 0px;
}

div input {
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: solid 1px black;
}

div input:focus {
  outline: none;
}

.richiedi {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px 50px;
}

.tabcosti {
  background-color: darkorange;
  border: solid darkorange 1px;
}

.border {
  border: solid darkorange 1px;
}

.black {
  color: black;
}

.white {
  color: white;
}

.m-left-50 {
  margin-left: 200px;
}

.x-small {
  font-size: x-small;
}

.tabcosti2 {
  border-top: 0px;
  border: solid darkorange 1px;
}

.margin-left {
  margin-left: 20px;
}

.info {
  width: 215px;
  height: 20px;
}

.info2 {
  width: 75px;
  height: 20px;
  margin: 10px;
}

.small {
  font-size: small;
}

.unbtn {
  border: 0px;
  width: 20vw;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: whitesmoke;
}

.unbtn:focus {
  outline: none;
  background-color: darkorange;
  color: white;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}

.btn {
  background-color: whitesmoke;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  flex-grow: 1;
  margin: 10px;
  height: 30px;
}

.btn2 {
  background-color: darkorange;
  color: white;
  border: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  flex-grow: 1;
  margin: 10px;
  height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="it">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="Normalize.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="Style.css">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>


<body>


  <div class="container justify flex-row">
    <div class="flex-col">
      <div class="justify flex-row">
        <h1 class="intro">Vuoi conoscere quali potrebbero <br> essere i <strong>costi</strong> della attività di <span class="orange">logistica</span> e <br>
          <span class="orange">trasporto</span> se affidassi i tuoi prodotti a <br> Gruppo Sinergia?</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="justify flex-row">
        <h2 class="orange">Calcola il tuo preventivo!</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="justify flex-row">
        <h3 class="tariffe"> <span class="bold tartitle">Tariffa di Gestione</span>: comprende le tutte le attività di gestione del prodotto, le attività di gestione<br> dell’ordine, le attività di gestione del reso e il trasporto nazionale e internazionale.</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="justify flex-row">
        <h3 class="tariffe"><span class="bold tartitle">Tariffa di Stoccaggio</span>: rappresenta il valore del singolo prodotto per la conservazione presso la<br> struttura di Gruppo Sinergia.</h3>
      </div>
      <!--^tariffe^-->
      <div class="justify flex-row">
        <p class="tabtitle">TIPOLOGIA PRODOTTO</p>
      </div>


      <!--Parte di codice con button-->
      <div class="justify evenly flex-row">
        <div class="flex-col">
          <div class="flex-row">
            <button id="sel" class="btn bottoneCategoria">Abbigliamento e Scarpe</button>
          </div>
          <div class="flex-row">
            <button id="sel2" class="btn bottoneCategoria">Pet & Food</button>
          </div>
          <div class="flex-row">
            <button id="sel3" class="btn bottoneCategoria">Sport e Tempo libero</button>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="flex-col">
          <div class="flex-row">
            <button id="sel4" class="btn bottoneCategoria">Elettronica e Informatica</button>
          </div>
          <div class="flex-row">
            <button id="sel5" class="btn bottoneCategoria">Casa e Cucina</button>
          </div>
          <div class="flex-row">
            <button id="sel6" class="btn bottoneCategoria">Auto e Moto</button>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="flex-col">
          <div class="flex-row">
            <button id="sel7" class="btn bottoneCategoria">Food & Beverage</button>
          </div>
          <div class="flex-row">
            <button id="sel8" class="btn bottoneCategoria">Belleza e Salute</button>
          </div>
          <div class="flex-row">
            <button id="sel9" class="btn bottoneCategoria">Altro</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>


      <div class="justify flex-row">
        <p class="tabtitle">DIMENSIONI PRODOTTO</p>
      </div>


      <div class="flex-row justify evenly">
        <div class="flex-col">
          <div class="flex-row">
            <button class="unbtn" onclick="hide()">Standard</button>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="flex-col">
          <div class="flex-row">
            <button class="unbtn" onclick="hide2()">Fuori misura</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>


      <div id="demo2" class="justify m-30 evenly bg flex-row hide">
        <div class="flex-col">
          <div class="flex-row">
            <p>Inserisci le dimensioni per il singolo prodotto (cm)</p>
          </div>
          <div class="flex-row justify evenly">
            <input class="small info2" type="text" placeholder="lunghezza">
            <input class="small info2" type="text" placeholder="larghezza">
            <input class="small info2" type="text" placeholder="altezza">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>


      <div id="demo" class="justify m-30 evenly flex-row bg hide">
        <div class="flex-col">
          <div class="align flex-row">
            <input class="cont" type="radio" value="Busta 35x25x3" name="Scatola"> Busta 35x25x3
          </div>
          <div class="align flex-row">
            <input class="cont" type="radio" value="Busta 39x31x5" name="Scatola"> Busta 39x31x5
          </div>
          <div class="align flex-row">
            <input class="cont" type="radio" value="Scatola 27x16x10" name="Scatola"> Scatola 27x16x10
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="flex-col">
          <div class="align flex-row">
            <input class="cont" type="radio" value="Scatola 24x15x17" name="Scatola"> Scatola 24x15x17
          </div>
          <div class="align flex-row">
            <input class="cont" type="radio" value="Scatola 37x28x8" name="Scatola"> Scatola 37x28x8
          </div>
          <div class="align flex-row">
            <input class="cont" type="radio" value="Scatola 44x30x9" name="Scatola"> Scatola 44x30x9
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="flex-col">
          <div class="align flex-row">
            <input class="cont" type="radio" value="Scatola 61x46x40" name="Scatola"> Scatola 61x46x40
          </div>
          <div class="align flex-row">
            <input class="cont" type="radio" value="Scatola 51x36x12" name="Scatola"> Scatola 51x36x12
          </div>
          <div class="align flex-row">
            <input class="cont" type="radio" value="Scatola 59x38x32" name="Scatola"> Scatola 59x38x32
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>


      <div class="flex-row bg m-7 justify evenly">
        <div class="flex-col">
          <div class="align flex-row">
            <input class="cont" type="radio" value="0-1 kg" name="Peso"> 0-1 kg
          </div>
          <div class="align flex-row">
            <input class="cont" type="radio" value="3-5 kg" name="Peso"> 3-5 kg
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="flex-col">
          <div class="align flex-row">
            <input class="cont" type="radio" value="1-2 kg" name="Peso"> 1-2 kg
          </div>
          <div class="align flex-row">
            <input class="cont" type="radio" value="5-10 kg" name="Peso"> 5-10 kg
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="flex-col">
          <div class="align flex-row">
            <input class="cont" type="radio" value="2-3 kg" name="Peso"> 2-3 kg
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>


      <div class="justify evenly flex-row">
        <div class="flex-col">
          <p>TARIFFA DI GESTIONE</p>
        </div>
        <div class="flex-col">
          <p>TARIFFA DI STOCCAGGIO</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="tabcosti justify flex-row">
        <div class="flex-col">
          <p>€ <span class="white">4,56</span></p>
        </div>
        <div class="flex-col">
          <p class="m-left-50">€ <span class="white">0,16</span> <span class="x-small">al mese</span></p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="flex-row tabcosti2">
        <div class="flex-col align">
          <div class="flex-row">
            <p>€ <span class="orange">3,12</span><span> spedizione</span> ITALIA</p>
          </div>
          <div class="flex-row">
            <p>€ <span class="orange">6,70</span><span> spedizione</span> EUROPA</p>
          </div>
          <div class="flex-row">
            <p class="margin-left">€ <span class="orange">6,70</span><span> spedizione</span> WORLDWIDE* ZONA 6</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="flex-col spacer"></div>
      </div>


      <div class="flex-row justify intro">
        <p class="tariffe">
          I valori sono calcolati con una media non superiore ai 10 ordini al giorni.<br> Per progetti con movimentazioni maggiori sono previste tariffe migliorative.<br> Se vuoi una quotazione ad hoc per iltuo modello di business e la tua tipologia<br>          di prodotti, contattaci!
        </p>
      </div>


      <div class="justify flex-row bg">
        <div class="flex-col">
          <div class="flex-row">
            <p>Nome e Cognome</p>
          </div>
          <div class="flex-row">
            <p>E-mail</p>
          </div>
          <div class="flex-row">
            <p>Telefono</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="flex-col">
          <div class="flex-row">
            <input class="small info m-14" type="text">
          </div>
          <div class="flex-row">
            <input class="small info m-14" type="text">
          </div>
          <div class="flex-row">
            <input class="small info m-14" type="text">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>


      <div class="flex-row m-7 justify">
        <button class="richiedi">
                    Richiedi un preventivo
                </button>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Just to let everyone know, the function in js i'm trying to make to solve this is just on the first button (ID sel) and i've tried telling the code to replace the colored class with the uncolored one.
I also know that it will look strange cause i have used 2 different ways to create a variable, but i found all the other function i used on stack overflow written like that (i just changed the ID name) but i don't know if there are differences on how i then added the other variables.

Comment: Please add only the relevant part of your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily achieve this using the below steps

First, remove all code in your javascript regarding `click` listener.

Then, store a list of buttons using this

```
var buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.bottoneCategoria');
```

Then, add this function. Basically, this function will be called whenever one of your buttons is clicked.

```
function onButtonClick(event) {
    // Get the button on which user clicked using event.target
    let clickedButton = event.target;

    // Loop over all your buttons and replace the btn2 with btn
    // This means all buttons will now be normal
    for (let i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
        buttons[i].classList.replace('btn2', 'btn');
    }

    // Finally change your clicked button from btn to btn2
    // This will make your clicked button to orange while rest will be normall
    clickedButton.classList.replace('btn', 'btn2');
}
```

Finally, loop over all your buttons and attach the function you created in previous step to all the buttons.

```
for (let i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
    buttons[i].addEventListener('click', onButtonClick);
}
```

Check the working code snippet for more details.

```js
function hide() {
  var x = document.getElementById("demo");
  var y = document.getElementById("demo2")
  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "inline-flex";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "inline-flex";
  }
  if (y.style.display === "inline-flex") {
    y.style.display = "none"
  }
}

function hide2() {
  var x = document.getElementById("demo2");
  var y = document.getElementById("demo");
  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "inline-flex";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "inline-flex";
  }
  if (y.style.display === "inline-flex") {
    y.style.display = "none"
  }
}

var buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.bottoneCategoria');

function onButtonClick(event) {
  let clickedButton = event.target;
  for (let i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
    buttons[i].classList.replace('btn2', 'btn');
  }
  clickedButton.classList.replace('btn', 'btn2');
}

for (let i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
  buttons[i].addEventListener('click', onButtonClick);
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
  background-color: white;
}

.flex-col {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.flex-row {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.justify {
  justify-content: center;
}

.align {
  align-items: center;
}

.evenly {
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}

.between {
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.border {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.m-0 {
  margin: 0;
}

.spacer {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.grow {
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.orange {
  color: orange;
}

.bold {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.bg {
  background-color: whitesmoke;
}

.tabtitle {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.tariffe {
  font-size: small;
}

.intro {
  text-align: center;
}

.tartitle {
  font-size: medium;
}

div h2 {
  font-size: xx-large;
}

.cont {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 35px;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
  margin-top: 12px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.m-7 {
  margin-top: 7px;
}

.m-14 {
  margin: 14px;
  padding: 0px;
}

div input {
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: solid 1px black;
}

div input:focus {
  outline: none;
}

.richiedi {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px 50px;
}

.tabcosti {
  background-color: darkorange;
  border: solid darkorange 1px;
}

.border {
  border: solid darkorange 1px;
}

.black {
  color: black;
}

.white {
  color: white;
}

.m-left-50 {
  margin-left: 200px;
}

.x-small {
  font-size: x-small;
}

.tabcosti2 {
  border-top: 0px;
  border: solid darkorange 1px;
}

.margin-left {
  margin-left: 20px;
}

.info {
  width: 215px;
  height: 20px;
}

.info2 {
  width: 75px;
  height: 20px;
  margin: 10px;
}

.small {
  font-size: small;
}

.unbtn {
  border: 0px;
  width: 20vw;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: whitesmoke;
}

.unbtn:focus {
  outline: none;
  background-color: darkorange;
  color: white;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}

.btn {
  background-color: whitesmoke;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  flex-grow: 1;
  margin: 10px;
  height: 30px;
}

.btn2 {
  background-color: darkorange;
  color: white;
  border: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  flex-grow: 1;
  margin: 10px;
  height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="it">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="Normalize.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="Style.css">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>


<body>


  <div class="container justify flex-row">
    <div class="flex-col">
      <div class="justify flex-row">
        <h1 class="intro">Vuoi conoscere quali potrebbero <br> essere i <strong>costi</strong> della attività di <span class="orange">logistica</span> e <br>
          <span class="orange">trasporto</span> se affidassi i tuoi prodotti a <br> Gruppo Sinergia?</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="justify flex-row">
        <h2 class="orange">Calcola il tuo preventivo!</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="justify flex-row">
        <h3 class="tariffe"> <span class="bold tartitle">Tariffa di Gestione</span>: comprende le tutte le attività di gestione del prodotto, le attività di gestione<br> dell’ordine, le attività di gestione del reso e il trasporto nazionale e internazionale.</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="justify flex-row">
        <h3 class="tariffe"><span class="bold tartitle">Tariffa di Stoccaggio</span>: rappresenta il valore del singolo prodotto per la conservazione presso la<br> struttura di Gruppo Sinergia.</h3>
      </div>
      <!--^tariffe^-->
      <div class="justify flex-row">
        <p class="tabtitle">TIPOLOGIA PRODOTTO</p>
      </div>


      <!--Parte di codice con button-->
      <div class="justify evenly flex-row">
        <div class="flex-col">
          <div class="flex-row">
            <button id="sel" class="btn bottoneCategoria">Abbigliamento e Scarpe</button>
          </div>
          <div class="flex-row">
            <button id="sel2" class="btn bottoneCategoria">Pet & Food</button>
          </div>
          <div class="flex-row">
            <button id="sel3" class="btn bottoneCategoria">Sport e Tempo libero</button>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="flex-col">
          <div class="flex-row">
            <button id="sel4" class="btn bottoneCategoria">Elettronica e Informatica</button>
          </div>
          <div class="flex-row">
            <button id="sel5" class="btn bottoneCategoria">Casa e Cucina</button>
          </div>
          <div class="flex-row">
            <button id="sel6" class="btn bottoneCategoria">Auto e Moto</button>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="flex-col">
          <div class="flex-row">
            <button id="sel7" class="btn bottoneCategoria">Food & Beverage</button>
          </div>
          <div class="flex-row">
            <button id="sel8" class="btn bottoneCategoria">Belleza e Salute</button>
          </div>
          <div class="flex-row">
            <button id="sel9" class="btn bottoneCategoria">Altro</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>


      <div class="justify flex-row">
        <p class="tabtitle">DIMENSIONI PRODOTTO</p>
      </div>


      <div class="flex-row justify evenly">
        <div class="flex-col">
          <div class="flex-row">
            <button class="unbtn" onclick="hide()">Standard</button>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="flex-col">
          <div class="flex-row">
            <button class="unbtn" onclick="hide2()">Fuori misura</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>


      <div id="demo2" class="justify m-30 evenly bg flex-row hide">
        <div class="flex-col">
          <div class="flex-row">
            <p>Inserisci le dimensioni per il singolo prodotto (cm)</p>
          </div>
          <div class="flex-row justify evenly">
            <input class="small info2" type="text" placeholder="lunghezza">
            <input class="small info2" type="text" placeholder="larghezza">
            <input class="small info2" type="text" placeholder="altezza">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>


      <div id="demo" class="justify m-30 evenly flex-row bg hide">
        <div class="flex-col">
          <div class="align flex-row">
            <input class="cont" type="radio" value="Busta 35x25x3" name="Scatola"> Busta 35x25x3
          </div>
          <div class="align flex-row">
            <input class="cont" type="radio" value="Busta 39x31x5" name="Scatola"> Busta 39x31x5
          </div>
          <div class="align flex-row">
            <input class="cont" type="radio" value="Scatola 27x16x10" name="Scatola"> Scatola 27x16x10
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="flex-col">
          <div class="align flex-row">
            <input class="cont" type="radio" value="Scatola 24x15x17" name="Scatola"> Scatola 24x15x17
          </div>
          <div class="align flex-row">
            <input class="cont" type="radio" value="Scatola 37x28x8" name="Scatola"> Scatola 37x28x8
          </div>
          <div class="align flex-row">
            <input class="cont" type="radio" value="Scatola 44x30x9" name="Scatola"> Scatola 44x30x9
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="flex-col">
          <div class="align flex-row">
            <input class="cont" type="radio" value="Scatola 61x46x40" name="Scatola"> Scatola 61x46x40
          </div>
          <div class="align flex-row">
            <input class="cont" type="radio" value="Scatola 51x36x12" name="Scatola"> Scatola 51x36x12
          </div>
          <div class="align flex-row">
            <input class="cont" type="radio" value="Scatola 59x38x32" name="Scatola"> Scatola 59x38x32
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>


      <div class="flex-row bg m-7 justify evenly">
        <div class="flex-col">
          <div class="align flex-row">
            <input class="cont" type="radio" value="0-1 kg" name="Peso"> 0-1 kg
          </div>
          <div class="align flex-row">
            <input class="cont" type="radio" value="3-5 kg" name="Peso"> 3-5 kg
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="flex-col">
          <div class="align flex-row">
            <input class="cont" type="radio" value="1-2 kg" name="Peso"> 1-2 kg
          </div>
          <div class="align flex-row">
            <input class="cont" type="radio" value="5-10 kg" name="Peso"> 5-10 kg
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="flex-col">
          <div class="align flex-row">
            <input class="cont" type="radio" value="2-3 kg" name="Peso"> 2-3 kg
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>


      <div class="justify evenly flex-row">
        <div class="flex-col">
          <p>TARIFFA DI GESTIONE</p>
        </div>
        <div class="flex-col">
          <p>TARIFFA DI STOCCAGGIO</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="tabcosti justify flex-row">
        <div class="flex-col">
          <p>€ <span class="white">4,56</span></p>
        </div>
        <div class="flex-col">
          <p class="m-left-50">€ <span class="white">0,16</span> <span class="x-small">al mese</span></p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="flex-row tabcosti2">
        <div class="flex-col align">
          <div class="flex-row">
            <p>€ <span class="orange">3,12</span><span> spedizione</span> ITALIA</p>
          </div>
          <div class="flex-row">
            <p>€ <span class="orange">6,70</span><span> spedizione</span> EUROPA</p>
          </div>
          <div class="flex-row">
            <p class="margin-left">€ <span class="orange">6,70</span><span> spedizione</span> WORLDWIDE* ZONA 6</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="flex-col spacer"></div>
      </div>


      <div class="flex-row justify intro">
        <p class="tariffe">
          I valori sono calcolati con una media non superiore ai 10 ordini al giorni.<br> Per progetti con movimentazioni maggiori sono previste tariffe migliorative.<br> Se vuoi una quotazione ad hoc per iltuo modello di business e la tua tipologia<br>          di prodotti, contattaci!
        </p>
      </div>


      <div class="justify flex-row bg">
        <div class="flex-col">
          <div class="flex-row">
            <p>Nome e Cognome</p>
          </div>
          <div class="flex-row">
            <p>E-mail</p>
          </div>
          <div class="flex-row">
            <p>Telefono</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="flex-col">
          <div class="flex-row">
            <input class="small info m-14" type="text">
          </div>
          <div class="flex-row">
            <input class="small info m-14" type="text">
          </div>
          <div class="flex-row">
            <input class="small info m-14" type="text">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>


      <div class="flex-row m-7 justify">
        <button class="richiedi">
                    Richiedi un preventivo
                </button>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>


  <script>
  </script>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I didnt' think i'd ever say this but.....Arigato itachi <3

Comment: @FilippoCanino Mata Kondo Da

Comment: but just to understand, why my first function about button, the big one with the .replace, doesn't work? logically it should, diocane, but i don't really understand why it doesn't

Comment: `this.a = a.replace(' btn2 ', 'btn ')`. Here `a` is a HTMLElement. So you should probably call `a.className.replace`. This could be one of the problems.
You can use the Chrome browser devtools to see if any error is coming. Then one by one you can fix them.